# Find thickness of the circle detected from contour?

Tags: c, opencv, geometry, contour, image-recognition

[image: want to detect the defect around this image]I am trying to detect the thickness of the circle which I have received from the code below, but I am unable to do so.

My basic idea is to move through the circle and if at any point the thickness is less than the other side, it means it's a defected circle.

I found this on google but I don't know how to put it in code:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/28180/measuring-edge-thickness-using-opencv

Code:

```
    IplImage* mainimg = cvLoadImage( "C:\\3.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); //change the name (image.jpg) according to your Image filename.
    if (!mainimg)
  {
    cout <<"Image can NOT Load!!!";
    return 1;
  }

    IplImage* srcimg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
    IplImage* inrangeimg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
    IplImage* erodeimg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
    IplImage* erodeimg1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
IplImage* subimg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
IplImage* finalimage=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);
IplImage* finalimage1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mainimg),mainimg->depth,1);


    cvAdaptiveThreshold(mainimg,srcimg,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY,11,-23);

    cvInRangeS(mainimg,cvScalar(50,50,50),cvScalar(255,255,255),inrangeimg);

    cvErode(inrangeimg,erodeimg,0,8);
    cvSub(inrangeimg,erodeimg,subimg,0);
    
    cvAnd(srcimg,subimg,finalimage,0);

    cvShowImage("final",finalimage);
    cvWaitKey(0);
```

After this, I know I need to find the contour but how can I get the thickness of the circle and travel through the circle to get the defected one? I don't want to get the pixel count and detect the defected circle...

When I run the above code, I get this image:

[image]

Comment: opencv's c-api is DEAD. code like that should no more be written. please use the c++ api.

Comment: @berak i do know it even if i shift in c++ the question remains the same. above allvthis a small code a big project already done in c. :-(

Comment: Can you be more specific on defect circles: Do they have non-uniform thickness in themselves (on side is thicker than the other), or they're thicker/thinner than other circles?

Comment: @Mahm00d non-uniform thickness in themselves

Comment: could you post the original image too

Comment: @sturkmen yes i hv uploaded the original img

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ideas:

**Using *perimeter*:**

1. Find the [enclosing circle](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1) of your shape (the ring).
2. Compare its perimeter to the shape's outer perimeter. If the shape has any abnormalities along the edge, its perimeter would be different (by a certain threshold you define)
3. The same can be done between the inner perimeter and the enclosing circle of the black inside (to find abnormalities along the inner side).

---

**Using *area*:**

1. Find the inner and outer enclosing circle of your ring.
2. Subtract the two areas to find the optimal area of the ring.
3. Compare this to the actual area of the ring and if different by a threshold, the circle is probably defect.

---

Of course, the first algorithm is more sensitive to the bumps which can be a good or a bad thing depending on your image and other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion you can try

```
.
.
.
cvAnd(srcimg,subimg,finalimage,0);

cvSmooth(finalimage,erodeimg,CV_GAUSSIAN,9,9);
cvThreshold(erodeimg,subimg,130,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cvShowImage("final image",finalimage);
cvShowImage("Smoothed and Threshold ",subimg);

cvWaitKey(0);
```

[image]

Comment: i am able to get till here but i want to detect if its is defected circle